# C++ unresolved reference between plugins

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have an application with plugins (loading using dlopen), it worked until now, when I faced problem I cannot solve on my own.

There are some plugins. One, lets say, contains some class - **MakerClass**. Second plugin, which is (indirectly, using "host" application calls) called by function in plugin One. Second plugin should look at some data and write result to **MakerClass**. But there is a problem - when some function in Second plugin calls (MakerClass*)mc->WriteNumber(12345), I've got unresolved symbol error.

In code lang, it is looks like this (simplified):

Host app:

```
HostApp::CallPlugin(void * data) { 
    this->second->Foo(data);
}
```

Plugin One, main.cpp, compiled to main.o and linked with maker.o to main.so

```
#include "maker.h" //here is defined MakerClass
....
void SomeFunction() {
    MakerClass mc;
    mc.DoSomeInitialization();

    this->host->CallPlugin(&mc);
}
```

Plugin Second, main.cpp:

```
#include "maker.h" 
SecondPlugin::Foo(void * data) {
    MakerClass * mc = (MakerClass*)data;
    mc->WriteData(1234); // This will raise problem - while dlopen (if RTLD_NOW) or when called (if RTLD_LAZY used)
}
```

It should be solution to use RTLD_GLOBAL, but every plugin have init. methods with same name, so it makes problem, especially when RTLD_NOW used and plugin Second is loaded before One.

So... exists some clean solution? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is virtual functions, abstract interfaces, IDL and other such things >:-)

Comment: I use "interfaces" using pure virtual methods for plugins, but this is just problem with one class having code in one .so and calling/runtime linking in another .so. Creating abstract class for this purpose looks like overkill for me.

Comment: OK, so at last I've tried your solution, it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `pluginA` contains `MakerClass` code that is needed by `pluginB`. If this is the case, then a clean solution is to isolate the `MakerClass` code in `pluginA` into a library that both `pluginA` and `pluginB` link to. This will allow you to use the library class between the two plugins cleanly.

Futzing around with `RTLD_LOCAL`/`RTLD_GLOBAL` to try to fix the problem is simply moving the underlying problem: `pluginA` depends on `MakerClass` and `pluginB` depends on `MakerClass`. If you don't address the real problem of the code being shared, then you end up in load-order hell. If you renamed `pluginA` to `pluginZ`, and `pluginB` loads before `pluginZ` you end up with the same undefined symbol problem.

Comment: Yes, I know it. Currently I tried user3369139's solution - it looks it should work. Btw, what would happen, if I link both plugins with MakerClass object? Will both plugins contain same compiled code?

Comment: If you linked the `.o`, they would each contain a copy of the compiled code.